# Httpclient in java without using any third party libraries

Tags: java, httpclient

I trying to automate few things in my workplace where we are not allowed to use internet (Not all website very few allowed).

Req: I have a form which has a single text box & a single submit button, I have to put something in the text box and submit the form. The response I need to parse the HTML and get a specific text. The pages are written in JSP

Constraint: I don't have access to third party libraries & have to work with Java 6.

Please put me in right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) comes default with java. You may consider using this API. This API does most of the functionality as Apache HTTPClient. Here is simple [example on how to use HTTPURLConnection](http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-simple-httpurlconnection-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like tamperdata from Firefox to capture the HTTP request that gets sent to the server, and then use HTTPUrlConnection (part of the JDK) to re-create that request.